# Generating a customer ID in a form

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have a customer table 'tblCustomer' that contains a primary key column called CustID. CustID refers to the Customer as their own ID number.

Now, I am in the process of creating a form that will allow people to add new customers. To do that, I need to generate a new CustID. My CustID starts at '10000' and go up by 1 each time. It is important to note that this field is a text field, not a number field.

There must be an ID, otherwise the record cannot be created as the primary key field is a mandatory field and is also tied to other relationships in the database.

As such, I am creating a button next to the ID field on the form that will generate an ID in the textbox. It needs to start at whatever the custID's highest key value is and increment it by 1. The problem is that it is a text field and cannot change.

I am unsure how to do this, personally. I have tackled it quite a few ways but all lead me back to the same spot - I don't know how to do this with custID being a text value rather than a numerical value. I have been thinking of doing a conversion of some sort as the calculation occurs but I have no idea how to do this at all.

I'm a bit of a newbie with Access, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you committed to keeping `CustID` as text type?  This would be simple if you changed it to autonumber and let Access supply the new values automatically.

Comment: If you want to keep track of your own Primary Key, the best way is to create a table of the key. Each time, extract the key and update the value (+1). As for the conversion, CInt and CStr will do nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all CustID's are numbers, you can do the following to get a new ID:

```
Dim strMax As String
Dim intMax As Integer

strMax = DMax("CustID", "<your table name>")
intMax = CInt(strMax) + 1
```

strMax will hold the current maximum id, and intMax will hold the new ID. If strMax contains a non numeric value however this code will fail - you would need an error handler to work around it.

Just need to put it in the buttons click event.

Hope this helps!

Simon